# HTML Java embedded applet ClassNotFoundException in Safari but not Chrome

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, safari, applet

I've written a Java Applet (in Eclipse, if that makes any difference) and embedded it in a local HTML file (which I will include). The applet code shouldn't be necessary because the problem lies in my HTML. The local HTML file works fine on Chrome, but Chrome is ending support for Java soon, so I'm trying to use the file on Safari. Theoretically, it should all function the same, but the Safari throws a ClassNotFoundException, while Chrome still runs it smoothly. The error reads "ClassNotFoundException", and the detail reads "chaos.chaos.class" (see HTML). (If it's relevant, I'm on OS X 10.10.3, with fully updated everything (I believe)) 
 And, apparently, I'm not allowed to post pictures, so I shall verbally describe the layout of my folders. The HTML file is in the same directory as another directory called 'chaos'. Inside this directory are the 'chaos.jar' and 'chaos.class' referenced in my code, along with 'Shape.class' which is not referenced but is necessary for the applet to run (it's referenced by one to the other files). Thank you in advance for any and all help and suggestions.

 UPDATE: I have also tried the HTML file on Firefox, and it works seamlessly there too. But I don't really like Firefox all that much, so I'm still searching for the answer.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
The Chaos Game
</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
<blockquote>
<applet code="chaos.chaos.class"
archive="chaos.chaos.jar"
width=900 height=900 
title="Chaos">
</applet>
</blockquote>
<br/>
<font size = "3">
Written by ...
</font>
</body>
</html>
```